# Capture batch output and save it in TXT File as log

Tags: powershell, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe, powershell-5.0

I'm running powershell script with batch file.

**My requirement is:-**

1. display the output in batch cmd and at the same time save output in TXT file. **Note,** as of now output getting saved in txt file but output is not visible in batch cmd.
2. Create a folder with system serial number in C drive and save txt file in that folder.

Batch File name:- **Check.bat**

Powershell script name:- **Check.ps1** (powershell file contains bulk commands which output will be displayed in batch file as a command prompt)

**Batch file code:-**

```
@echo off
for /F %%a in ('wmic bios get serialnumber') do call :Sub %%a
:Sub
if not "%*"=="" set SerialNumber=%*

xcopy "%~dp0*" "C:\windows\Temp\Compliance_Check" /q /s /e /y /i
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File %~dp0Compliance_Check.ps1 > C:\%SerialNumber%\output.txt
pause
```

Comment: The best move is to alter your Compliance_Check.ps1 because powershell can easily capture the output of any command into a variable, and from there you can output the variable to screen and also save it to a file. For example: `$command = .\program.exe; write-host $command; $command | out-file -append "log.txt"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED RESPONSE**

The batch file becomes:

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File %~dp0Check.ps1
pause
```

And, using Tee-Output which takes the output of the previous command in the pipeline and sends it both to a file and to the next command in the pipeline, the PowerShell will be something like:

```
$serialNumber = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_BIOS | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber
$logFilePath = "C:\$serialNumber\posh.log"
if (-not (Test-Path -Path (Split-Path -Path $logFilePath -Parent))) { md $logFilePath }
if (Test-Path -Path $logFilePath) { Remove-Item -Path $logFilePath }

Copy-Item -Path 'C:\test\source\*' -Destination 'C:\test\Temp\Check' -Recurse -Force | Tee-Object -FilePath $logFilePath

Get-Date | Tee-Object -FilePath $logFilePath -Append

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\test\Temp\Check' -Recurse | Tee-Object -FilePath $logFilePath -Append
```

You need to use -Append on Tee-Output after the first time, if you want it all in the same file.

This might not meet your exact requirements but you've edited the question substantially twice since I started trying to answer it and I'm out of time.

Comment: I see you've edited your question since I wrote that.  I think it would be easier to do everything in PowerShell.

Comment: How we can do that in powershell?

Comment: Now I have 1 query, where do I need to paste this code in PowerShell (at the beginning or at the end?)

Comment: The lines up to and including Copy-Item are the necessary bits and would go at the top of your PowerShell script.  The other bits were just examples to show you how to use `-Append` on subsequent commands.